# Can I use Variable in an INSERT SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, variables, select, insert

I am copying data from access.mdb file which I have already extracted then i will copy to mysql table with a references from another table.

access.mdb already show from a certain PDO statement. Next step is to insert it to a table from with a relationship from an existing table. Below is my table and some of my code.

table 1 (accessfile.mdb)

```
 id | owner | info    
----+-------+---------
 1  | 122   | apple
 2  | 122   | orange
 3  | 133   | apple
 4  | 133   | grape
 5  | 144   | lemon

$owner=row(owner) <- stored in a variable
```

table 2 (mysql tbl_owner)

```
 id | code | name
----+------+-----------
 1  | 122  | grace    
 2  | 133  | james    
 3  | 144  | liza
```

data should be inserted to table 3 with a new code base on table 2 owners id.

table 3

```
 id | owner | info    
----+-------+-----------   
 1  | 1     | apple    
 2  | 1     | orange    
 3  | 1     | apple
 4  | 2     | grape    
 5  | 3     | lemon
```

this is my statement so far.

```
INSERT INTO table3
SELECT tbl_owner.id, tbl_owner.code, $
FROM tbl_owner 
WHERE tbl_owner.code=$owner;
```

Comment: The code needs to be formatted. Please don't rollback edits which format your code.

Comment: Which platform have you used to define the variable?

Comment: i use php running this script